# How to hide some columns in ng grids's Column Menu

Tags: angularjs

How to hide some columns in ng-grids's Column Menu. I have more than 10 columns in grid, i don't want show all the columns in Columns Menu, i want to show only 7 columns in Columns Menu. How can i do that
.....Thanks in advance.

Comment: see here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16954058/how-to-hide-column-in-ng-grid

Answer (score -1):

You can also hide the columns dynamically by adding this code after you define the grid;

```
var pos = $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs.map(function (e) { return e.field; }).indexOf('yourFieldName');
if ($scope.basicAdmin || $scope.superAdmin)
    $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs[pos].visible = true;
else
    $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs[pos].visible = false;
```

The angularjs grid array is **$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs**. Change the gridOptions to the name of your grid.

Replace "**yourFieldName**" with whatever field you are wanting to hide. Next, put whatever condition you want to test.

This took some time to figure out. Hopefully, it will save others some time.

Comment: Just want to add that any of these columns can be made visible by a user if he plays around with the javascript, so if you have important data you dont want certain people to see, dont send it to client side

Comment: user3219752 ,  please notice that your answer is not related to the question!,  Rajesh kumar asked to hide columns from the Column menu on the right top end - and not hide columns from the grid as your answer suggested.

Comment: BlueChameleon, great point.  I wrote this for a project for nonsensitive information inside company firewall.   If you have sensitive data, definately don't send it to the client.   Thanks.